# Ciphertext size of RSA, ELGamal, and EICES encryption

Tags: encryption, rsa, ecies

I have to make a choice based on the minimum stored data, so I would like to know which encryption protocol is better in terms of the size of the resulting ciphertext for very short plaintexts (8 to 40 bytes)? RSA? ElGamal? EICES?

Comment: RSA should generate 256 byte ciphertexts, ElGamal 512 byte and ECIES up to 88 bytes.

Comment: Can you provide a reference of these information? or how do you find these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compressed point - which makes up the ephemeral public key for ECIES - only takes the key size, possibly prefixed by an indicator byte with value `02` or `03` (which is required by some libraries).

So for e.g. BrainpoolP256R1 you'd get 32 bytes, and maybe one more for the byte indicating that it is a compressed point. That is enough to derive a data encryption key. As the public point is already ephemeral there is no need for an IV. After key agreement you would just require the ciphertext bytes - which for CTR is identical to the plaintext message size.

So that would come down to a ciphertext size of 32 + 8..40, or 40 to 72 bytes (not including the indicator byte), while still giving you 128 bits of security (and no protection against quantum computers of sufficient size, of course). That's way less than the 256 bytes required for RSA, while RSA would be less secure on top.

Comment: Actually, for ECIES, you don't need the bit; you can do ECDH using only the x coordinates.

Comment: ... even more so when you use Curve25519 instead of bp256r1

Comment: Adjusted for the indicator byte, with some clarification (sometimes using the normal procedure to load the public key should be preferred). Basically you can do with a single bit, and then use the other 7 bits for something else (multiple curve sizes, versioning etc.).

Comment: Also isn't your calculation for ecies missing the authentication tag?

Comment: @SEJPM Yesno. The minimum size for encryption is using CTR mode and the question reads **stored data**. For in place encryption that just requires confidentiality this is the minimum amount. For sending data or if integrity / authenticity is required then an authenticated mode such as EAX could be used with a 8 byte authentication tag (as using GCM mode with a shorter tag is not recommended). Good point though, other users may have different requirements.

Comment: @ Maarten Bodewes is the answer also valid for “secp256r1” when using ECIES with AES-CBC and without point compression? How should I calculate the size of the output of ECIES encryption when using “secp256r1” and AES-CBC without point compression?

Comment: Yes, it's the same; *practically* speaking, the Brainpool curves and secp256r1 aren't any different (see the safecurves site for theoretical differences). CBC requires padding or ciphertext stealing (not used much). With CBC you just need to add 1 to 16 bytes (the block size of AES) if you use the common padding modes - bit padding or PKCS#7 compatible padding. Note that many here consider CBC legacy mode, but it is of course still secure if you don't need integrity / authentication.